# How to open Mac documents .page, on LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice

I need to open text documents. "page" and
keynote presentations also keep in osx, how do I open or install
this extension in libreoffice?

Comment: you can try [CloudConvert](https://cloudconvert.com/pages-to-docx)

Answer (score 45):

If you don't have access to an Apple operating system, use Apple's no-cost 'in-browser' version of Pages to export it in a format that you can open with LibreOffice. Unfortunately, Pages doesn't have OpenDocument (ODT) export, (as of 2015), but it does have DOCX (Microsoft Word) and PDF (Portable Document Format) exports.
[image: screenshot if www.icloud.com]

1. With a recent version of Firefox, or Chrome, visit Apple's iCloud website: https://www.icloud.com .
2. If you don't have an Apple ID, register for one at no cost.
3. Log in with an Apple ID.
4. Open Pages. https://www.icloud.com/#pages
5. The site asks you to upgrade to a supported browser to use all the features. Unfortunately, no Linux browsers are supported (as of 2015) so ignore this message: export still works.  (It also may ask you to upgrade to iCloud Drive. I am not sure what this means, but you probably need to accept this to be able to open Pages.)
6. Drag your Pages document onto your browser. It shows you an editable version of your document in a kind of file manager view
7. Double-click the icon for your uploaded document.
8. In a new browser tab, it shows you a word processor interface to your document.
9. Select the tools menu (a spanner/wrench icon in the top right of the screen).
10. Choose 'Download a Copy'.
11. Export as PDF or as Microsoft Word (.DOCX).
12. With LibreOffice, navigate to your downloads folder and open the document.

I tried with a short sample Pages document and LibreOffice 4.4. I found that DOCX format gave a more faithful copy than PDF.

Reference: https://help.apple.com/icloud/#/mm6f8c20082b

[image: iCloud after logging in]
[image: Drag your Pages document onto your browser]
[image: Pages file manager view shows an icon for your document]
[image: Select 'Download a Copy ...']
[image: Choose a download format (I recommend 'Word' if you plan to open it in LibreOffice]
[image: Downloading to your Linux computer]

*Update*

I just found that as a shortcut, you don't have to open the document in Pages. You can use the option menu in Pages desktop view to 'Download a Copy ...'.  Use the option(menu) key on your keyboard, or click your secondary mouse button (usually the right button on a right-handed mouse). See screenshot.
[image: secondary click menu on iCloud Pages desktop view]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: This is is the a simple, clean and supported Solution to this problem. Thanks @dcorking +1

Comment: This is also exactly why I hate apple. (+1)

Comment: @Taylor you mean because they use a proprietary format like Microsoft but allow you to extract some useful information from the file by converting to a zip (unlike Microsoft)?

Comment: @Snowcrash yes. Although I regret using the word "hate." I wish to replace that with "do not prefer."

Comment: Note: Icloud no longer appears to be working correctly on Firefox on Windows 11. Fails to connect to iCloud server.

Comment: The answers here are intended for Ubuntu Linux. That said, as of May 2023, www.icloud.com works for me on Windows 11 in Firefox 113.

Comment: At least Micro$oft, when they duped ISO, made their format somewhat interoperable. Apple should be nailed for being anticompetitive.

Answer (score 19):

As of 2015, LibreOffice (version 5) is capable of opening this format.

https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=LibreOffice-Apple-Pages-Numbers

Comment: There is basic support, but sadly buggy (as of version 5.4.2), often messing up the layout. But still worth trying first.

Answer (score 18):

If you are stuck and just need some of the content of the file, you can rename it to .zip (e.g. example.pages to example.zip) and unzip it.

The unzipped files will include some PDFs and PNGs which is some of the text and image content of the document.

This worked for what I needed just now, but of course it is not as good as getting the file  converted properly on a Mac.

Comment: +1 this works (though sometimes there is no PDF in the archive) and it can be done entirely offline with free software.

Answer (score 7):

There are many free online conversion tools for this.

[cloudconvert.com](http://cloudconvert.com) can convert to doc, docx or [PDF](https://cloudconvert.com/pages-to-pdf). Just upload your documents, and it converts in the cloud.

Comment: Took me five seconds, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working on Linux Mint (Ubuntu) by upgrading the `libetonyek` library. From my [answer in Ask Libreoffice](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/224764/cannot-open-apple-pages-documents/?answer=312333#post-id-312333):

> I've read high and low about this issue and finally got it working.
>
> I'm running
>
> - Linux Mint 20.1 (based on Ubuntu 20.04)
> - LibreOffice 6.4.7.2
> - libetonyek 0.1.9
>
> This issue seems to have been fixed in libetonyek 0.1.10, but that
> wasn't included in the LibreOffice I installed by default.
>
> I found the .deb package for the latest version here:
>
> https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/impish/amd64/libetonyek-0.1-1/0.1.10-1
>
> After installing this I can now see the content of .pages files

Comment: Installing the deb file worked like a charm, and you don't have to upload your document to some 3rd party website, this really should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative:
In Pages, you can open Preferences, and under the General tab, select Save New Documents as Packages. This saves the file as a package (folder) which includes a PDF file, and you can open the folder, navigate to the PDF and open it. You won't be able to edit.

Answer (score 0):

If, like on my system, your .pages file appears as a folder, go inside that folder, select all files and sub-folders and compress everything into a .zip file. Then rename that file to .pages and you should be able to open it with the method described above.