# How to set LibreOffice as the default app to open Pages documents

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, apple, zip, mime-type

Since [LibreOffice can open and edit Pages documents](https://askubuntu.com/a/996630/1044036), I would like to set LibreOffice as the default app to open Pages, Numbers, and Keynote documents. For the sake of this question, I will refer to all of these collectively as `.pages` documents, since the process will likely be the same for all of these.

The problem is that `.pages` documents are just renamed `.zip` files which can be uncompressed and opened by any archive utility.

Opening the Pages documents from `File > Open` in Libreoffice functions how I want it to. Also, in Nautilus, right-clicking a Pages file, choosing "Open with other application", then choosing Libreoffice works fine.

The problem is that if I set the default application for Pages documents to be Libreoffice, it also changes the default application for `.zip` files.

Checking the mime type for pages documents reveals the following:

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype ~/Documents/Document.pages
application/zip
```

How would I set the default application for `.pages` documents to LibreOffice?

Comment: If it is simple, also, how would you choose a new default icon for `.pages` documents? This is probably another question, but if it's easy to answer, feel free to add it!

Comment: This [requires changes to be made in two places](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mime-support/+bug/1878617) and may be done for you in a future release of Ubuntu. There is no "simple way" to do it correctly at this time, though.